# Slow query entity framework

Tags: c#, mysql, sql, entity-framework

I noticed that one of my queries with entity framework is so slow. I thought that problem was that I was using contains but I did not get "any" speed difference. The table I am doing this query to have around 4k entries so I cannot understand why it takes 20 seconds to do this. I am using mysql with the latest .net connector

```
var errorMessages = msgs.Where(m => m.Type == 1 && 
            (m.StatusCode == (int)ErrorCode.AbsentSubscriber || 
             m.StatusCode == (int)ErrorCode.AbsentSubscriber || 
             m.StatusCode == (int)ErrorCode.Deleted ||
             m.StatusCode == (int)ErrorCode.Error ||
             m.StatusCode == (int)ErrorCode.Expired ||
             m.StatusCode == (int)ErrorCode.InvalidDestination ||
             m.StatusCode == (int)ErrorCode.Rejected ||
             m.StatusCode == (int)ErrorCode.SubscriberError ||
             m.StatusCode == (int)ErrorCode.Undeliverable ||
             m.StatusCode == (int)ErrorCode.UnknownSubscriber))
            .GroupBy(m => m.StatusCode);

foreach (var error in errorMessages)
{
    var eSum =
            db.ErrorSumMessages.SingleOrDefault(
                m => m.ErrorCode == error.Key 
                && m.MessagesId == oldHourlyMessage.MessagesId);

    if (eSum != null)
    {
        //This gets called
        eSum.Count += error.Sum(m => m.MessageCount);
        db.Entry(eSum).Property(m => m.Count).IsModified = true;
    }
    else
    {
        db.ErrorSumMessages.Add(new ErrorSumMessage
            {
                Count = error.Sum(m => m.MessageCount),
                ErrorCode = error.Key,
                ErrorText = error.First().StatusText,
                MessagesId = oldHourlyMessage.MessagesId
            });
    } 
}
```

Comment: db.ErrorSumMessages is db entity?

Comment: Have you tried to step through the code to see where it's slow? Is it the first query or the loop that takes the juice?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your code, in each iteration called db query - `db.ErrorSumMessages.SingleOrDefault`. If errorMessages contains 4K records, you get 4K queries!

To decrease numder of db queries, select required (or all) db.ErrorSumMessages before foreach statement:

```
var localErrorSumMessages = db.ErrorSumMessages.ToList();
foreach (var error in errorMessages)
{
   var eSum = localErrorSumMessages.SingleOrDefault(....); // selecting from collection in memory
```

Comment: I don't agree with you.Why ? B'cos do you know how many records are there on 'ErrorSumMessages' table ? May be 16K. Then what'll happen ?

Comment: Yes, it may be problem, but execute a lot of queires to db it is a very, very bad practice. If ErrorSumMessages contains 16K, then all logic of this method should be refactored, to use only one, single query

Comment: Yep,retrieving one big data tree may be faster than 4k small data traversal request through the wire.Hmm..OP must test this with his db and then he should decide it.+1

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you also query the `ErrorSumMessages` in the main query:

```
var errorMessages = msgs.Where(...)
            .GroupBy(m => m.StatusCode)
            .Select(g => new 
                 { 
                   StatusCode = g.Key,
                   eSum = db.ErrorSumMessages
                            .FirstOrDefault(
                            m => m.ErrorCode == g.Key 
                              && m.MessagesId == oldHourlyMessage.MessagesId),
                   Messages = g
                 })

foreach(var row in errorMessages)
{
    var eSum = row.eSum;
    var error = row.Messages;
    // rest should work unaltered, except error.Key => row.StatusCode
    ...

}
```

You have to use `FirstOrDefault` otherwise EF will throw "The methods 'Single' and 'SingleOrDefault' can only be used as a final query operation".

Comment: Hmm, I usually don't care about getting accepted or not, but in this case I really can't recommend the approach you seem to choose.